# .click function not working when the event is called by element created by another function

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have this function that create an element

```
function AddPayment(ID)
{
    showForm = $('#AddPaymentForm').html();    
    $('#divAJAX_'+ID).html(showForm);  

    $(".cancel").click(function(){ AddPayment(ID); });
}
```

Coming from this

```
<div id='AddPaymentForm'>    
       <span class='button' id='cancel' class='cancel' >Cancel</span>
</div>
```

I wanted that function to place the element in here

```
<div id='divAJAX_ID'></div>
```

I also wanted that function to create an onclick function on my span, but it isn't working.
I guess the problem is coming from placing the

```
$(".cancel").click(function(){ AddPayment(ID); });
```

at the wrong placement. I've tried all the possible place but I can't still work this right.

What's wrong?

Comment: Could you make a fiddle (http://jsfiddle.net/) of it? It would help a lot.

Comment: I'm confused about `AddPayment(ID)` inside the event handler. Clicking "Cancel" will basically overwrite the existing form, i.e. reset the values of every field (I assume you have more elements in `#AddPaymentForm`). Is this what you intend to do?

Comment: `<div id='divAJAX_ID'></div>`, ID here is dynamic or static, because I see something like `$('#divAJAX_'+ID).html(showForm);` (is it '#divAJAX_ID')

Comment: @FelixKling I have conditions in my AddPayment(ID) function. I just simplied it here so it can be understand easily.

Comment: @KhanhTO ID in <div id='divAJAX_ID'></div> is dynamic

Comment: @ivory-santos so that is the reason to bubble event on document.

Comment: Out of curiosity, why the -1 (whoever did it)? It is not a bad question, or is it? Should the OP have tried harder to catch the double 'class' before asking for help? I don't get it...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have **two class attributes** on the same element. It should be something like:

```
class="button cancel"
```

instead of

```
class="button" id="whatever" class="cancel"
```

It is probably causing trouble to jQuery.

See how it start working on this fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/pvNrg/2/

First, your question as the html:

```
<div id='AddPaymentForm'>
    <p>Coming from this</p>
</div>

<span id='cancel' class='cancel'>Cancel</span>

<p>I wanted that function to place the element in here</p>

<div id='divAJAX_ID'></div>

<p>I also wanted that function to create an onclick function on my span, but it isn't working. I guess the problem is coming from placing the ... at the wrong placement. I've tried all the possible place but I can't still work this right.</p>

<p>What's wrong?</p>
```

And the javascript:

```
$(function () {

    function AddPayment(ID) {
        showForm = $('#AddPaymentForm').html();
        $('#divAJAX_' + ID).html(showForm);
    }

    $(".cancel").click(function () {
        AddPayment('ID');
    });
```

});

Comment: Oh greate @jaywalking101 I haven't noticed that I included two classes at different place. I simply add them on same holder then it works fine. THANKS a lot!

Comment: Good catch, though your code example doesn't achieve the same as the OP has. They are using `ID` from the `AddPayment` function inside the event handler, whereas you are using the string `'ID'`.

Comment: @ivory- santos: this code also creates a `.cancel` and inserts into  `$('#divAJAX_' + ID)`. I think the `.cancel` inside the `$('#divAJAX_' + ID)` does not work. Is it a problem?

Comment: @FelixKling Yeah, I didn't understand where the ID param should come from. But it will be a string (or number) right? To be concatenated and then become an id (a string). Isn't it to? I just used 'string' to make simpler. Anyway, the problem was somewhere else. =)

Answer (score 1):

For dynamically created elements ,You have to do [event delegation](http://api.jquery.com/on/)

```
$(document).on("click", ".cancel" , function(event){
  alert($(this).text());
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$("#AddPaymentForm,[id^=divAJAX_]").on("click", ".cancel" , function(event){
  alert($(this).text());
});
```

Attach the delegated event handlers only the list of containers you need to monitor (not the document) if you need to save performance (you don't need to monitor all the `.cancel`). With this approach, the event does not have to bubble up more levels. If you have anther element that is parent of `AddPaymentForm` and all `divAJAX_`. You could write like this:

```
$("#anotherContainer").on("click", ".cancel" , function(event){
      alert($(this).text());
    });
```

Comment: OP is not setting data to $('#AddPaymentForm') and setting to $('#divAJAX_'+ID)  which is a dynamic ID.

Answer (score 0):

Use this code

```
function AddPayment(ID)
{
   var showForm = $('#AddPaymentForm').html();
   var container = $('#divAJAX_'+ID);

   container.html(showForm);
   container.find(".cancel").click(function(){ AddPayment(ID); });
}
```